# How to cancel ASIFormDataRequest in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, asihttprequest, asiformdatarequest

How to cancel a ASIFormDataRequest using blocks?.

```
__block ASIFormDataRequest *req = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];  

[req appendPostData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[req setDelegate:self];
[req setCompletionBlock:^{
    [self parseResult:req];
}];
[req setFailedBlock:^{
    [self requestWentWrong:req];
}];
[req setTag:tag];
[req startAsynchronous];
```

Is there any way to cancel this request in a button action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in Your button action Event as req is class memeber variable:

```
-(IBAction)YourbuttonactionEvent
{ 
  if(![req isCancelled]) 
  {
    // Cancels an asynchronous request
    [req cancel];
    // Cancels an asynchronous request, clearing all delegates and blocks first
    [req clearDelegatesAndCancel];
}
```

Comment: please note that therequest is __block ASIFormDataRequest *req. does it matter?